# Clone two different internal disks into one external

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clone, clonezilla

I want to clone two internal (SSD+HDD) into one external HDD.

In HP x360 laptop I have two hard disks. First is SSD (128Gb) partitioned as GPT and it has Win 10 installed on it (with Recovery, EFI Sys and Boot partitions) and second is HDD 2.5"(1Tb) partitioned as MBR with 3 partitions. File system is NTFS on all basic partitions. One of the partitions on HDD has VMWare Virtual Machines saved on it (VMWare is installed on SSD). Used space together is 700 Gb.

I would like to clone both disks into one HDD (1Tb) and install that HDD in to another laptop. Is it possible with Clonezilla or any other software? Will other laptop become copy of original?

Comment: You won't be able to combine a MBR and GPT disk together.  If both disks are running Windows 10, use the built-in tool, to perform a conversion to GPT then recreate the disk image.  If you are only talking about the single partition, after you restore the GPT image, create a new partition and restore the image of the single partition to that partition.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but Windows 10 will not be activated on the new computer and
may miss some drivers needed for new hardware.

As far as copying the data:

1. Use a disk cloning product to clone the system disk to the new disk after
   formatting it as GPT (for example
   [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/help/clone-hard-disk.html))
2. Use Disk Management to reduce the size of the system partition on the new disk
   (if required), allocate the other three partitions, and assign them drive-letters
3. Copy the files for the three partitions to their respective new partitions.

The new disk should now be ready.